# Invert binary tree; getting Nonetype error when i have specifically asked to proceed only if the node is not None

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search, nonetype

```
#code taken from leetcode so treenode is predefined

# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        temp=root
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                left_temp=node.left
                node.left=node.right
                node.right=left_temp
            if node.left:           #Keeping a check only if left node is not None then proceed
                dfs(node.left)
            if node.right:          #Keeping a check only if right node is not None then proceed
                dfs(node.right)
        dfs(temp)
        return root
```

`node.left:`--> getting an error saying Nonetype object has no left attribute.

As per Python `None` is falsey,so `node.left` should be false and the process shouldn't go any further.

I can run the code by keeping `if node.left` and `if node.right` within the `if node`, but I want to know why it won't work this way and where am I slipping.

Comment: root can be None ... None.left is an error

Comment: even when the root is not none, I am getting error

Comment: somehow the node is becoming None ... if its not root i dont really see how that happens off hand ... but somehow it is None ... hence the error that NoneType has no attribute left. ..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't execute any code when the first `if` condition is not true, yet when it is false your next `if` condition tries to access a `left` attribute of `None`. These other two `if` statements should be placed inside the first `if` block:

```
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        temp=root
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                left_temp=node.left
                node.left=node.right
                node.right=left_temp
                if node.left:  #Only executed when node is not None
                    dfs(node.left)
                if node.right:
                    dfs(node.right)
        dfs(root)
        return root
```

With this change your code will work as expected.

But you can make this code more elegant:

- These other `if` conditions are not really needed: just make those recursive calls and leave it to that call to detect that you passed a `None` value.
- There is no need to use `temp`. Just work with `root` directly.
- Swapping can be done in a more pythonic way using tuple assignment.
- You could have `dfs` return the node, so that the caller can use that return value immediately in the swap, and with the initial call of `dfs`

```
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        def dfs(node):
            if node:
                node.left, node.right = dfs(node.right), dfs(node.left)
                return node
        return dfs(root)
```